# How do I remove the Apache "/icons/" and "/icons/small/" folder alias?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

By default, Apache has two alias folders called /icons/ and /icons/small/ that are full of very old fashioned icons.  Both folders are not physical folders in my domain directory on the server, as they are autogenerated aliases.

How do I hide or disable them, as I can't comment out the alias in `httpd.conf` as there is no alias for any icons folder in the `httpd.conf` file, and there is no `alias.conf` file?

I am using AWS Linux 2.

Comment: Are you sure? `grep -r "/icons"` will probably show that there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/etc/httpd/conf.d directory, open autoindex.conf file and replace from "Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks" to "Options MultiViews FollowSymlinks"